# How to declare a constant TPoint?

Tags: delphi, constants, point

Good morning,
I am trying to declare constant TPoint in Delphi, how do you do that ?

None of the following works

```
// ...
const POS_A : Tpoint = (3,3);  
const POS_B : Tpoint = Point(3,10);
const POS_C : Tpoint = Tpoint(3,20);
const POS_D : Tpoint = TPoint.create(3,30);
// ...
```

Any clue ?

Comment: It's covered very clearly in the documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Record_Constants

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation on [constants](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Record_Constants), specifically the part about records, you write

```
const
  MyPoint: TPoint = (X: 3; Y: 7);
```

Comment: Thx Andreas, accepted in 10 mins. @David could not find my answer and SO doen't even sugest my question or anythig like in suggestions. You can have fun linking another  topic but I think it is just better to go straightforward here.

Comment: @MartialP: I am not sure I understood that question. `TPoint` is a standard Delphi RTL type. It is a record with two integer members `X` and `Y`. If you want to create a constant point, `(3, 7)` say, you need to use the syntax above. `MyPoint` is the name of the constant, `TPoint` is the type, and then you specify the members. The compiler needs all that information to understand what the constant is.

Comment: Just ignore that. My IDE did underline  "X"  and "Y" as undeclared so I tough I had to declare TPoint again like in the documentation, but in fact it was just IDE going mad because it compiles and run just fine.

Comment: @MartialP: Yes, Error Insight is known to produce false positives. I believe that has been improved in Delphi 10.4.

Comment: @MartialP I assumed that there would be a duplicate, but when I searched I could not find one.  All the Qs I found were for more advanced issues with typed constants. Regarding duplicates, it is important to mark them if possible. That adds structure to the site. That's why we do it, not because it is "fun". Finally, can I gently commend the documentation, at least for the basic language. It is pretty comprehensive, and it should be your first port of call for a question like this.